# window.location.href and window.open prevent each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying open a pdf in a new url and also redirect user to homepage. But these 2. and 3. lines of "if" block prevent each other. Page is redirecting to homepage but window.open() is not working.

```
 if(result.status == 'success'){
      hideSplashScreen();
      window.location.href = webContextPath+"/user/userhome";
      window.open(result.message, '_blank').focus();
 }
```

Comment: Pop up blocker will block that pop up FYI

Answer (score 3):

Actually `window.location.href = webContextPath+"/user/userhome";` leaves the current page, so probably the `window.open` never runs...

Have you tried calling `window.open(result.message, '_blank').focus();` first and only then `window.location.href = webContextPath+"/user/userhome";`?

Answer (score 1):

Flip the Sequence : Call this first window.open(result.message, '_blank').focus(); first

```
if(result.status == 'success'){
      hideSplashScreen();
      window.open(result.message, '_blank').focus();
      window.location.href = webContextPath+"/user/userhome";
 }
```